# Does Facebook's dialog/friends still work?

Tags: facebook

We've been using `http://www.facebook.com/dialog/friends/?id=...&app_id=...&redirect_uri=...&display=popup` to let users add friends in our app.

But lately it's stopped working. I've searched the docs but couldn't find any reference to the `dialog/friends` anymore. Has it been deprecated/removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog to add friends has been removed a long time ago afaik. Here´s a list of all available dialogs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui

Comment: Thanks. What's the alternative now for adding friends?

Comment: there is no alternative, you have to use facebook.com or the official facebook apps